# as3 combine elements of array that match, use math to count the numbers

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

My head is spinning around for not finding the solution to my problem. I've searched all over the web to find an answer or solution to get it done. I thought what I want is simple to achieve, but I can't get it right. Maybe it is a lot more difficult or I am just looking wrong.

I've made a as3 project where content will be writen to a .txt file. Each day there will be made a new file and on this txt file will be saved al the data of the actions of the day.

The txt file looks like this:

```
79, 2-1-2015, Orange,1,4.00, 15:59:43
79, 2-1-2015, Blue,1,1.00, 15:59:43
80, 2-1-2015, Orange,1,4.00, 16:2:52
80, 2-1-2015, Black,1,1.00, 16:2:52
```

(actionumber, date, article, amount, cost, time)

I now want to read this data in my project and look for the same articles, count the amounts and costs and put it back as one row in a new file. For example, based on above txt file:

```
2, Orange, 8.00
1, Blue, 1.00
1, Black, 1.00
total: 4, , 10.00
```

I know I can read and write files via Filestream. 
After I read the file, I've put the content into a array and split each row in a different element. But then, when I need to compare, and do the math, I'm stuck.

I tried to use IndexOf to search in the array,but I don't know what to do next.  I read about .concat and saw examples of duplicates being removed from an array. but I want duplicates based on the article (amount and cost may vary) combine and count instead of deleting. And I think that is a different cup of tea?!

Has some one a good example or can point me in the right direction? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `Object` ( or associative array ) to stock your articles with their names as keys like this :

```
var url_request:URLRequest = new URLRequest('data.txt')
var url_loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader()
    url_loader.addEventListener(
        Event.COMPLETE,
        function(e:Event){
            load_data(e.target.data);
        }
    )
    url_loader.load(url_request);

function load_data(data:String):void {

    var actions:Object = {};

    // convert all data to an Array
    var temp_arr:Array = data.split(String.fromCharCode(13));

    for(var i = 0; i < temp_arr.length; i++){

        var action_line:String = temp_arr[i];
        // convert every line to an Array
        var action_arr:Array = action_line.split(', ');

        var article:String = action_arr[2];
        var amount:int = action_arr[3];
        var cost:int = action_arr[4];

        if(actions[article]){       

            var t_a:Array = actions[article]
                t_a[0] += int(amount);      // cumulate amount
                t_a[2] += int(cost);        // cumulate cost
            // update article
            actions[article] = t_a;

            // example : actions['Orange'] = [1, 'Orange', 4]
            // =>        actions['Orange'] = [2, 'Orange', 8]

        } else {

            // create new article as an Array
            actions[article] = [int(amount), article, int(cost)];

            // example : actions['Orange'] = [1, 'Orange', 4]

        }

    }

    var amounts:int = 0;
    var costs:int = 0;

    for(var action:String in actions){
        amounts += actions[action][0];
        costs += actions[action][2];
        trace(actions[action][0]+', '+actions[action][1]+', '+actions[action][2].toFixed(2));
    }

    trace('total : '+amounts+', '+costs.toFixed(2));

    // gives : 
    //
    //  1, Black, 1.00
    //  2, Orange, 8.00
    //  1, Blue, 1.00
    //  total : 4, 10.00

}
```

Of course you have to add the part that will save these data into a text file.

Hope that can help you.

Comment: you helped me a lot! The code is great and is exactly what I needed.. Thank you!